# Trig function not plotting correctly in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I have the following snippet

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black, domain=0:10] plot({\x}, {cos(((9 - \x)/8)*3.141592)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When I compile the file, however, the plot just produces a straight line. I think this means that it's not sampling points correctly, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The units of `\x` are the problem, if you tell tikz that you are trying to deal in radians then it will cooperate! Let tikz know to treat that number as a quantity in radians by including the letter 'r' before closing the parenthesis after `cos`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[black, domain=0:10] plot({\x}, {cos(((9 - \x)/8)*3.141592 r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comes out like so: [image: wavey]