# Drawing functions with TikZ/pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm trying to plot some functions using TikZ but it's getting all messed up. For example,

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[thick, black, ->] (-0.2, 0) -- (5, 0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[thick, black, ->] (0, -0.2) -- (0, 3) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[thick, blue] plot [domain=0:3.141,smooth, variable = \x, samples = 400] (\x,{cos(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

I saw a bunch of topics using axis and addplot to plot the function, but I don't wanna use axis and addplot keeps giving back an error (I'm guessing it's because I'm not on an axis). What should I do?

Comment: Try changing your code to `cos(\x r)` and it works. You need to specify you are working with radians as explained in [Trig function not plotting correctly in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250685/trig-function-not-plotting-correctly-in-tikz).

Comment: @DJP it works, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image you can draw also on the following way:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
          > = Straight Barb,
trig format = rad,  % <--- determine angle units
     domain = 0:pi
                    ]
    \draw[->] (-0.2, 0) -- (4, 0.0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0, -1.1) -- (0, 1.5) node[above] {$y$};
    \draw[thick, blue] plot [samples = 401] (\x,{cos(\x)}); % at so many samples effect "smooth" negligible
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: marked code line determine used angle units. In your case they should be radians. This function worksalso in `pgfplots` diagrams.